# Getting a part of URL in apache

Tags: php, apache, wildcard, vhosts

I have set wildcard vhosts in my apache like

```
<VirtualHost *>
  ServerName wildcard.test.com
   ServerAlias *.test.com

   DocumentRoot = /var/www/test
   # other configuration for this app here

</VirtualHost>
```

I have created some sub domains like `front.test.com` and `admin.test.com`. I just want to know if there is a way in **APACHE** to get the first part of the URL like in above cases, I want **test** and **admin** and send it to my server side language some how. I repeat that I am looking for a possible way in apache, as people always say

> you can not always trust what $_SERVER returns
>   I will go for server side after confirming that there is not any way doing it on apache 
>   Thanks

Comment: Um, what? Why can you not trust what $_SERVER returns? $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] will return the hostname of your server, why can you not trust this?

Comment: Ok leave my "Not trusting lines". Isn't there any other way of doing this outside Php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$_SERVER can be trusted. Everything in $_SERVER is 'true'. But that doesn't say you should trust it.
It holds the Query_String, HTTP_HOST, ... and these come from a request the user made. It is the user that shouldn't be trusted.

If a person types in foo.test.com then 'foo.test.com' will be the value of $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];

So I don't really see what the problem is.

Comment: @Ahmed You also have access to the HTTP_HOST int .htaccess:  %{HTTP_HOST}
So you could create a rewrite rule:
RewriteCond  %{HTTP_HOST} front.test.com